# addClass(undefined) vs. addClass(null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, undefined, chain

Sometimes I'd like to add class in chain, under some condition. What value would be semantically most appropriate to add no class?

Example:

```
$(".element").doSomething().addClass(condition ? "special-class" : undefined).doSomethingElse();
```

Or:

```
$(".element").doSomething().addClass(condition ? "special-class" : null).doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: Why not just blank ("")?

Comment: @ruakh Yes, I meant `.addClass`, it's late :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`$.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead:

```
$(".element").doSomething().toggleClass("special-class",condition).doSomethingElse();
```

As [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) mentioned it, there is a difference. If `condition` is falsy, it will actually remove the class if it was present before. With your logic, the class can only be added, not removed.

Comment: That's it! I didn't know `.toggleClass` has second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery checks input parameter like this:

```
typeof input == "string"
```

so either **null** or **undefined** will behave the same way

Comment: Thanks. This question is 5 years old, I had known back then that they will behave the same. My question was which one is more correct semantically, but today I know that in cases like mine, choosing `null` or `undefined` don't matter that much.